# How to dispose of views that are removed by MvxListView adapter

Tags: android, listview, mvvmcross

I have a list of lists of lists, implemented as a MvxListView.

It looks like

-Parent-
MvxListView containing items of Fruit

-HumanCell-
Some forms and an MvxListView containing items of ExistingFruitColors

-ExistingFruitColors-
Some forms and an MvxListView containing items of ExistingShapes

-ExistingShapes
Some forms

I noticed that when I'm navigating in my app (this closing and reopening the ViewModel) as well as when I'm scrolling in the listview, I'm seeing some garbage collecting GC_BRIDGE appearing in the debug screen. In 2 minutes, memory consumption can grow from 6MB to 12MB for a simple 30 cells list.

The fact that a lot of object are created is not a problem, but I'm curious if it's possible to override a method either in the adapter or in the list to garbage or dispose of some views and listeners.

There is no changes happening in the list, but there's a lot of memory variations.

I'm thinking about listening to ViewModel changes and only update the listview canvas when a real change happens, but that's an ugly solution.

Is there something I should be aware when nesting binded lists into binded lists?

Can I force the MvxListView to just draw my items and not attempt to do anything else with it?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something I should be aware when nesting binded lists into binded lists?

IMO, generally, this is normally better done as a single list with sections/groups. It's easy to use header/footer cells for each section and to use a custom adapter to decide which cell to draw.

Having lists within lists can also give a strange touch experience for the user - since the lists can scroll independently - but if this is the UX you desire, then this should be OK.

> Can I force the MvxListView to just draw my items and not attempt to do anything else with it?

Sorry, but I'm not entirely sure what this question means.

In general, MvxListView (and ListView) only draw the cells/items currently on screen - recycling is used on cells to reduce the memory used.

When a Activity is Finished, then the MvxListView's ItemSource is set to `null` - which should result in the ListView memory being cleared up when the Activity is complete.

One thing to be aware of is that in order to estimate the total list scroll size, then the list view does initially have to consider all the list items - it does have to estimate how high each cell is.